# Does brace to correct posture work?

Tags: orthopedics, posture, effectiveness

I've had bad posture (humpback) for years, and no amount of reminding myself seems to help. I'm looking into chest braces that are supposed to help.

However, [all the online reviews](https://www.google.com/search?q=does+correct+posture+brace+work&oq=does+correct+posture+brace+work) seem to come from sites trying to sell braces.

Do we have studies showing the effectiveness of these braces?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an paper that might help you:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3554027/

The short conclusion is

> "Application of the scapular brace improved shoulder posture and
>   scapular muscle activity, but EMG changes were highly variable. Use of
>   a scapular brace might improve shoulder posture and muscle activity in
>   overhead athletes with poor posture."

Have you found any other sources? Have you tried it yourself?